# OpenCV 2.2: bad argument in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp

Tags: c++, c, opencv, camera

i have the above error when I'm trying to compile my code. Its a very very very simple function and I cant figure out why I have the problem. The worst is that i cant even find where array.cpp is in the opencv folder so i cant see whats wrong. Does anyone know? pls help!

```
int imgreg_capture_image()
{
    /*********************Try capturing an image from the camera first*************************************/

    CvCapture* imgregCapture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
   if ( !imgregCapture ) {
     fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );

     exit(-1);
   }

     // Get one frame
     IplImage* frame = 0;
     frame = cvQueryFrame(imgregCapture);
     if ( !frame ) {
       fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
       return -1;
     }

   //save the image into a file
    cvSaveImage( CAPTURE_FILE, frame );

   // Release the capture device housekeeping

    cvReleaseCapture(&imgregCapture);

    cvReleaseImage(&frame);

   return 0;
   /***************Finish Try capturing an image from the camera first*************************************/
}
```

Comment: The array.cpp file is in `modules/core/src/array.cpp`. It might help if you give a bit more details about the error you get - can you post the complete output of the compiler ? Could you also indicate which line numbers refer to which lines in the code you posted ?

Answer (score 1):

It is [stated in the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#queryframe) that the images returned by `cvQueryFrame` don't have to be released. In your case delete

`cvReleaseImage(&frame);`

The de/allocation of `frame` is managed internally by the capturing device.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: If you wish to further process your image, use `cvCopy(frame, yourManagedImage);`, and work with `yourManagedImage` instead of the original `frame`.